# Getting module name from thread information

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, winapi, module

I'm attempting to get the module name for each thread in a process. Process explorer shows the name of the module associated with each thread no problem. I can enumerate all modules and all threads in my current process with no problems, and get data related to them. My current method of deducing the associated module is the following:

```
if(module.BaseAddress < thread.StartAddress && (module.BaseAddress + module.BaseMemorySize) > thread.StartAddress)
{
    // this is our module ;)
}
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be a concrete way of doing it. The xfire_toucan.dll module shows in procexp fine:

```
1972 : xfire_toucan.dll!ToucanSendGamestatsConsoleLine_V1+0x80
```

In the list of modules, it shows with a base addr of `0x10000000` and a size of `0x26b000`, giving us a max memory addr of `0x1026b000`. However, the associated thread start address is `0x775e2ca0`, which is part of an allocated block of memory in the process outside the module's main memory range.

Any idea how to get the module like ProcExp does?

I know C and C#, so either is fine, but my project is C# so that's preferred :]

Answer (score 4):

Process explorer isn't showing you the module associated with each thread.  Windows does not maintain this information.  It's showing you the symbol name for the thread's entry point.  This will usually (but not always) be a function in the module that started the thread.  If you want to retrieve this sort of information in your program, you can use the debug help API.  They're probably using the StackWalk64 function to retrieve the entry point name.

Comment: How would walking the stack be reliable? There's no set stack offset for the thread's function. There is also no definite set of calls before the thread function: http://stackoverflow.pastebin.com/e1TLxwuj

Comment: Better description of what I'm talking about: http://stackoverflow.pastebin.com/cFNjueAq

Comment: Actually, there is.  In order to do a stack walk, you need the .pdb file associated with the module.  This file contains the size of each stack frame, among other things.